# Font 'Kaiti SC Regular' does not contain script 'CJK'

Tags: xetex, cjk, xecjk

I use `xelatex` to support Chinese,

```
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=Kaiti SC Bold]{Kaiti SC Regular}
```

but it occurs warnings:

> *fontspec warning: "script-not-exist" , Font 'Kaiti SC Regular' does not contain script 'CJK'.

How to handle this warning ?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using Mac OS. Font `Kaiti SC Regular` in Mac OS is a TrueType font, while `script` is an OpenType feature. So it doesn't have any `script` information.

Actually, `Kaiti SC Regular` can be used normal although `fontspec` will give this warning. If you must suppress this warning, you may use another font.

`STKAITI` can be used here. It has the same Chinese name `华文楷体` and almost the same appearance with `Kaiti SC Regular`.